# Firefox slow dns lookup due to IPv6 in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: networking, 13.04, firefox

Just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 13.04 64 and ran into a very strange problem.
Chrome is working fine but Firefox sometimes connects to sites very slow. It can take around 10 seconds before Firefox starts to load something(I can see something connecting to or look up).

I actually found out how to fix it. Just go to about:config and set **network.dns.disableIPv6** to true and Firefox starts loading pages very fast

But my question is what's changed since Ubuntu 12.10. In my Ubuntu 12.10 **network.dns.disableIPv6** is set to false and Firefox works properly.

Comment: Report that as a bugg.  It should not work like this.
The DSN resolver should happen in parallell with IPv6 and IPv4.See RFC 6555, "Happy Eyeballs"
But unless you have set up IPv6 yourself, your computer shouldn't even try to use any IPv6 DNS server.